# How to insert a list as the first column in the DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that consists of the three columns.

```
print('my_list')
3.50913843e-05     4.573843e-05     7.0543e-05
1.64190123e-04     6.795123e-04     1.64190123e-04
4.19101449e-04     3.219e-04     2.154e-04
4.40226697e-04     1.557897e-04     4.40226697e-04
3.11362684e-04     3.11362684e-04     3.11362684e-04
```

But I have another list (consisting of floats) that I want to add as the first column in the DataFrame.

```
Additional_list=[0.25,1.24865,2.541,3.1,4.4582]
```

Therefore, the desired outcome is the following:

```
0.25     3.50913843e-05     4.573843e-05     7.0543e-05
1.24865     1.64190123e-04     6.795123e-04     1.64190123e-04
2.541     4.19101449e-04     3.219e-04     2.154e-04
3.1     4.40226697e-04     1.557897e-04     4.40226697e-04
4.4582     3.11362684e-04     3.11362684e-04     3.11362684e-04
```

Is there any simple pandas command for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `concat`:

```
lst = pd.Series([0.25,1.24865,2.541,3.1,4.4582]) # <-converted to series
pd.concat([pd.Series(lst), df], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Created `df` by OP's mentioned sample by copying its contents and using:

```
df=pd.read_clipboard();
df
   1st      2nd      3rd
0  0.000035 0.000046 0.000071 
1  0.000164 0.000680 0.000164 
2  0.000419 0.000322 0.000215 
3  0.000440 0.000156 0.000440 
4  0.000311 0.000311 0.000311
```

Here is the list which we need to insert into 1st column's place as per OP's requirement.

```
Additional_list=[0.25,1.24865,2.541,3.1,4.4582]
```

Could you please try following.

```
idx=0
df.insert(loc=idx, column='A', value=Additional_list)
df
```

Here is the [df.insert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) documentation too.